# formating text, rows to columns in python

Tags: python, database, text, row

I need to change the format of a text file, the input text contains several chunks begins with an `event code`. inside each chunk there are several rows, each row contains one or more parameters, what I need is an output that each event code will be a `ROW` and all the parameters related to that chunk will be in columns like a spreadsheet or a database.
here is an example for a chunk, as can be seen the event name is `internal-soho-missing-call` and parameters are `hour`, `minute`, ... `ue-context`,`rnv-id-1`,....

my question is what is the best way to do it using python, (the OS is Solaris 10)? should I  use a database? which database is working fine with python? my expected number of rows is maximum 1000 and maximum number of columns is 30. consider the limitation of installing new packages and databases, as I am not the system admin, is there any way to do this just using python default packages?

```
scannerId '00000000 00000000 00000001'B,
hour 7,
minute 4,
second 38,
millisec 238,
events internal-soho-ds-missing-call :
   {
      ue-context valid : 3045, 
      rnv-module-id valid : 22, 
      c-id-1 valid : 12623, 
      rnv-id-1 valid : 2, 
      event-trigger valid : event-value-event-1a    (15), 
      action valid : event-value-no-action  (11), 
      scrambling-code-cell-1 valid : 446, 
      cpoid-ec-no-cell-1 valid : 29, 
      rsdd-cell-1 valid : 12, 
      scrambling-code-trigger-cell valid : 2, 
      cpoid-ec-no-trigger-cell valid : 23, 
      rsdd-trigger-cell valid : 9, 

   }
```

and my desired output should be as below:

```
   EVENT                                hour   minute  second   millisec   ue-context  rnv-module-id  ... 
events internal-soho-ds-missing-call     7       4      38       238          3045        22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have stored the following content in file: key_Value.txt

```
scannerId '00000000 00000000 00000001'B,
hour 7,
minute 4,
second 38,
millisec 238,
events internal-soho-ds-missing-call :
   {
      ue-context valid : 3045, 
      rnv-module-id valid : 22, 
      c-id-1 valid : 12623, 
      rnv-id-1 valid : 2, 
      event-trigger valid : event-value-event-1a    (15), 
      action valid : event-value-no-action  (11), 
      scrambling-code-cell-1 valid : 446, 
      cpoid-ec-no-cell-1 valid : 29, 
      rsdd-cell-1 valid : 12, 
      scrambling-code-trigger-cell valid : 2, 
      cpoid-ec-no-trigger-cell valid : 23, 
      rsdd-trigger-cell valid : 9, 

   }
```

this should solve your problem:

```
import string
intermediate=""
with open("key_Value.txt", 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        intermediate+=line.strip() + "\n"
i = intermediate.splitlines()
heading = []
values = []
splitstring = " "
for s in i:
    if "{" in s:
        splitstring = " : "
    if not (("{" in s) or ("}" in s)):
        try:
            s=string.replace(s,",","")
            key = s.split(splitstring,1)
            key[1]=string.replace(key[1]," : ","")
            key[1]=string.replace(key[1]," :","")
            heading.append(key[0])
            values.append(key[1])
        except:
            pass

head=""
for h in heading:
    head+=h+"\t"

val=""
for v in values:
    val+=v+"\t"

print head
print val
```

Hope this helps.